# How to include the gtk library in code blocks?

Tags: c, gtk, codeblocks

I wanted to make a graphic interface in C and i have found some comments on forums recommending GTK.
I use Code Blocks and till now have only made console applications. This is my first time having to add an external library. I have tried to use a tutorial online but some that i have found tell you to download files from links that are dead. I have read some forums too but i didn't get much from them.

*https://www.gtk.org/docs/installations/windows/*

*https://www.msys2.org/*

What I had done is first downloaded the MSYS2. I followed all the instructions to the point. From both websites. I haven't downloaded Glade since i assume that it isn't necessary for what i want to do but in the end i don't know.

When running Code Blocks i chose build a GTK+ project and it prompts me with a question on where the GTK location is (after naming the project and all that). I choose the **C:\msys64\mingw64** since thats where the lib and the include files are. It also prompts me with the Global Variables Editor in which i have added all the paths which are as follows:

Base:    **C:\msys64\mingw64**

Include: **C:\msys64\mingw64\include\gtk-3.0\gtk** (I have tried changing this up but still doesn't work)

Lib:     **C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\gtk-3.0**

When i finalize the wizard for the project it tells me:

**Script Error: The path you entered seems valid, but the wizard can't locate the following GTK's include file: gtk.h in it.**

The problem is that when I open the folder **C:\msys64\mingw64\include\gtk-3.0\gtk** I can see a gtk.h file, so it isn't missing so that the wizard can't find it.

My only idea is that there are conflicts with code blocks expecting gtk2 and getting gtk3. But i have seen a tutorial on how to fix that and the problem only occurs upon building the project so i assumed that that isn't a problem, but if you think it is just comment and i will try changing it up.

I run on a Win 7 64-bit system.

PS: I use code blocks in uni and so i would like it if i could solve this problem, but in the end uni isn't really always up to date so if you think that there is a better compiler/environment in which i could more easily include the libraries please do tell. I only ask for the solution to be free for my shallow student pockets lol.

Thank you on your help :)

Edit: There was a recommended question, but when I did what the answer said, I wasn't able to include the library, maybe I'm missing something that someone with more experience would do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Integrating GTK+3.24.21 (Glade) libs with Codeblocks (C)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62952585/integrating-gtk3-24-21-glade-libs-with-codeblocks-c)

Comment: @Michi I will take a look and try it out, since its more of a workaround if i understood correctly. Making an empty project and then listing it as a gui aplication. Edit: I have been trying it out for some time now and wasnt able to build a project with a #include <gtk/gtk.h> in it.

Comment: if you are interested in GTK3 with CodeBlocks 20.03 then [Just follow this 2 videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLN_MPJUQgPVopEfWiFX88_zUzk08ZdrIc).